# XMLHttpRequest Vs HttpRequest

Tags: asp.net, ajax, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

Does anyone know, what an `XMLHttpRequest` enables a web page to do, which cannot be done using a normal `HttpRequest`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[`XMLHttpRequest`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) is a standard javascript object that allows you to make HTTP Requests from the browser in javascript.

[`HttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx#) is a *server side* object that represents a *request* to the server.

In summary - one works in the browser, the other in the web server. They also have *completely* different roles. `XMLHttpRequest` is for fetching web resources within the browser. `HttpRequest` represents an incoming request.

Comment: Surely they both represent outgoing requests! Hence the work request, anything that is incoming is a response!  I thought XMLHttpRequest was as you said, a means of making a http request via javascript and that a HttpRequest is an object that is built into the browser that represents a request made via the url bar in the browser's gui.

Answer (score 2):

while the standard HTTP request makes a 'synchronous' call and must wait for the response and makes a page-reload (you always get a new html-page to display) XMLHttpRequest may be used sync (not typical) and async (the better way) without a page-reload. you may ask for the response with javascript and the response is usually xml- or json-data that you may process with js and update parts of your page through the use of dom-methods that manipulate your document ... so you don't need an entire page reload because all of that is running in the 'background'